# Why isn't one of my variables defined? -Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm fairly new still to python, and I'm trying to create a "word guessing" program, and part of that is creating a function that takes the inputted letter and then compares it to a list of letters, however it does not seem to recognize my definition of the variable "guess" in `while (guess != ans):`, any thoughts on why that is?
(Also here's my code as a reference):

```
def main():
  ans = str("a")
  guess = str("null")
  letterList = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z]
while (guess != ans):
    if(letterList[0] == ans):
      guess = letterList[0]
main()
```

Error:
`NameError: Name 'guess' is not defined on line 5`

Comment: Is that indentation correct? I looks like the `while` loop is outside of `main`, which means it's running before you call `main`, and in a scope in which neither `ans` nor `guess` is defined. Also, the definition of `letterList` is almost certainly invalid (unless you have global names bound for `A`, `B`, etc.). Make sure you're providing the actual code; I'm guessing this is a typo, but we have no way of knowing if you're being slapdash about cutting it down to a [MCVE].

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, provide the full error message including the stack trace. As an aside, you **really** shouldn't be learning Python 2, which is passed it's official end of life. You **really** should be learning Python 3. Python 3 **is** Python now. The only good reason to use Python 2 nowadays is essentially the same reasons to use Python 1... because you are being forced to because of legacy software.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah! That was it, I'm so stupid, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry! I didn't know! It still should run though, also I'll edit it to include my error! Sorry I'm still learning Stack Exchange, also I realize that Python 2 is archaic, however the programming class I'm taking is required as a prerequisite to take the next level course, which teaches Python 3.X

Comment: That's a terrible course then :( Teaching new users a dead dialect is a crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language and the interpreter relies on indentation to distinguish the different blocks of code.
If you don't know what that is, here's something you could read:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/

The problem in your code lies within the while loop.
Because your variable "guess" is within the scope of the function main, so only other variables and functions inside "main" can see it.

Also, your letterList has a problem, because each character should be within quotes(" " or ' ') otherwise python interprets them as variables which are not even defined.

Your while loop is in a different scope, the "global" scope and that is why your program doesn't recognize the "guess" variable.
And your loop is infinite because "guess" will always be different than "ans" is not changing.
If you could express what you want to accomplish in a better way, I could help you out.

```
def main():
    ans = str("a")
    guess = str("null")
    letterList=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    while (guess != ans):
        if(letterList[0] == ans):
            guess = letterList[0]
```

Comment: Ah thank you I didn't see that! Sorry for being dumb I'm still kinda new to all this!

Comment: My pleasure. And we all start somewhere ;)